# Omniauth + windows live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, windows-live-id, windows-live-messenger, windows-live

how do I configure a new windows-live provider using omniauth?

I tried the following with no success:

```
use OmniAuth::Strategies::WindowsLive, key, secret
```

and

```
provider :windows_live, key,secret
```

Comment: Hello John. It is an old issue, but did you ever find a way to make it work? I am stuck with `Could not find matching strategy for :windowslive. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-windowslive)`, but I've added it to my project and `bundle install` even displays it...

Comment: Ah, nevermind, that was a missing require. It seems to work fine on the second format.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the issues here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues#issue/26. Windows live seems to be a bit off the OpenID standard...

Comment: Windows Live ID is an OAuth service. Unfortunately, Microsoft shut down their OpenID project :-(